# Ambiguity of import modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a Python library that looks like this (contains packages):

```
|-- python_lib/
    |-- plotting.py
    |-- verification.py
    |-- io.py
    |
    |-- ensemble/
        | -- plotting.py
        | -- verification.py
```

However, I am having problems with ambiguous module imports. In `ensemble.plotting.py` I want to import the `verification.py` module from the top level (`python_lib`):

```
# ensemble/plotting.py
import verification.obs as verobs
```

However, I get an import error as this tries to import the `verification.py` module from the ensemble directory, rather than the top level of the library.

I thought that the "abslute imports" feature would solve this:

```
from ..verification import obs
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

How do I target `python_lib/verification.py` as an import from `python_lib/ensemble/*.py` without trying to import the local package version?

I am using Python version 2.7.

Comment: `from python_lib.verification import obs`?

Comment: @leovp python_lib is not a package, it just happens to the the base directory that the source is in.

Comment: Try to add each sub-directory empty file called __init__.py.
look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py?rq=1 also

Comment: how about make the directories pagckages by adding empty __init__.py

Comment: @nivhanin Each sub-directory does have an __init__.py file. The top level doesn't as it is not a package (just a directory).

Comment: sounds good than, I'm pretty sure that the post I add can really help you. Have a look.

Comment: Is there a `python_lib/__init__.py` file? Else, you cannot import from it. Please update your file tree with these files for clarity.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl My PYTHONPATH environment variable has a path to `python_lib`. The point is that `python_lib` might be called something else...

Comment: Well then `..` is above the top-level for the internal import for the package and you cannot import from it.

Answer (score 1):

1. All your directories should contain files `__init__.py`, or they won't be recognized as packages.
2. Your directory `python_lib` must be a known path. You said in a comment that your `PYTHONPATH` contains a path to `python_lib`, so that seems good.
3. If you start with e.g. `python_lib/ensemble/verification.py` as your main entry point, then the directory `python_lib/ensemble` shadows your directory `python_lib`, and you have to manually tell Python that your script belongs to that package.

Like this:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
     __package__ = "pythonlib.ensemble"
     import pythonlib
```

After that is done, this should work:

```
from ..verification import obs
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a **hacky** solution that would work but is generally discouraged.

You can modify python path in place when you have to omit conflicts. Like that:

```py
import sys  # needed to make it work

tmp = sys.path[0]
sys.path = sys.path[1:]  # ugly and hacky thingy

# import stuff you need (would work with __init__.py in a base dir)
from python_lib import verification
from ..verification.obs import obs

# fix path back
sys.path.insert(0, tmp)
```

I just tested this pattern and it seems to work (Python 3.6.0)

Answer (score 0):

There are some rules that has to be followed while creating packages and modules.

1. Make sure there is `__init__.py` file as a part of your package. Every python package is expected to have this file
2. While the module is looked it happens in 3 ways.

A very good documentation is available [Module-search-path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Usually while building projects it a practice to create a lib package and add sub directories based on different categories and add the main directory to the PYTHONPATH variable. This make the module available for other programs.